# Sprite animations in paper.js

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, sprite, paperjs

I'm working on my project in Paper.js.

In the part of It, I need to use sprite with animation.

To examplain It, I've got a space ship that can be everywhere on the screen, and there is an effect of disortion that happens sometimes.

I got prepared a spritesheet with 10 frames, and all I want is use Paper.js RASTER class to load It and animate on every frame.

The problem is in the positions, that I don't know how to calculate them...

When I load a raster

```
let slide = new Raster({
    source:   'assets/sprite.png',
    position: [0, 0]
});
```

I see center of a very long image, when I need to see the first frame.

My idea was to use group with containts mask (square)

```
let mask = new Rectangle({
  position: [220, 100],
  size:     [186, 154],
});
```

That I can change position dynamically and animate the spread at the same time.

Is It possible that way?
It would be cool, If I cant calculate the position of raster against the mask, but for me now It seems impossible.

Anyone have idea how to attain this in a simple way?

Cheers.

Comment: I just got started using paper for a project and was looking for an answer to this very question. I'm going to explore it and see what I learn.

Comment: Ok I made a demo, I'm just not sure now what you mean by "animate the spread"?

Comment: I haven't done this myself, but i believe it is possible using clipping or "clipMask": http://paperjs.org/reference/group/#clipmask

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into this in my project. The key is using a group with a pivot point. This code is admittedly unfinished and in raw javascript but it should give you a good idea:

```
var Sprite = paper.Group.extend({
    _class: 'Sprite',
    initialize: function Sprite(url, size) {
        var maskSize = size || new paper.Size(256, 256);
        var that = this;

        this._raster = new paper.Raster(url);
        this._raster.pivot = new paper.Point();
        this._raster.on('load', function () {
            that._spriteSheetWidth = Math.floor(this.size.width / maskSize.width);
            that.setIndex(that._spriteIndex || 0);
        });
        this._clipRect = new paper.Path.Rectangle(new paper.Point(), maskSize);

        Sprite.base.call(this, [this._clipRect, this._raster]);

        this.clipped = true;

        // Just use a blank point if you want the position to be in the corner
        this.pivot = new paper.Point(maskSize.divide(2));
    },

    setIndex: function (index) {
        if (typeof this._spriteSheetWidth !== "undefined") {
            // TODO: FINISH SPRITE SHEET IMPLEMENTATION
        }
        this._spriteIndex = index;
    }
});
```

I'm not actually using sprites in my project anymore so I never finished the implementation. But the complicated concepts should be completed above. Namely the way that paper.js implements pivot points and clipping masks. The position of an object is the center of it's bounds by default... this is kind of unweildy for a lot of reasons, like an images position will appear to change when it loads etc... or when the contents of a path change. So I like to set a pivot of `0,0` immediately after making any object. The next key section is that clipping masks only work on Groups. And finally you can extend the Group class to make a standard Sprite class.

Normal sprite shifting of `this._raster.position.x` and `this._raster.position.y` should finish this implementation off.

Edit: Finished my implementation... https://jsfiddle.net/willstott101/vgxq9kak/